# How to avoid multiple calls to google direction API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

We’ve a requirement where we need to calculate “Driving Time” from location A to location B, also there could be several way points between location A & B. Currently we’re managing this requirement successfully using Google Direction API.

Now we’ve a situation where we’ve to calculate this driving time for multiple vehicles, situated at different locations. Which means start point will vary but waypoints and destination will remain same.

Now do I need to call direction API for each vehicle separately or is there any other API by which I can obtain this information in single call.

Comment: Have you looked at [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)?

Comment: @xomena I need driving time not distance. I know for distance I can use distance matrix API.

Comment: Distance Matrix API also returns a "duration" field where you can see a driving time. Here is an [example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=1356%20Bass%20Pro%20Drive%2C%20Manteca%2C%20CA&destinations=24505%20West%20Dorris%20Avenue%2C%20Coalinga%2C%20CA%2093210)

Comment: @xomena it does not allow us to include way points.

Answer (score 0):

I remove a segment after you pass it, [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x23kq.gif)
If minimum distance from your location to segments, I will call  to google APIs again